# ng-repeat: Identify Change of Element Value In Sorted List

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a table using ng-repeat. This table has a column called `Season` which is obviously populated by `{{episode.season}}`. The source data is sorted by season.

I want to add a class to the last `<tr>` of each season, i.e. when there is a change of season, e.g.

```
--------------------------
EPISODE 1 | SEASON 1
--------------------------
EPISODE 2 | SEASON 1
--------------------------
EPISODE 3 | SEASON 1       <- THIS ROW SHOULD HAVE DIFFERENT FORMATTING
--------------------------
EPISODE 1 | SEASON 2 
--------------------------
```

Using vanilla JavaScript, I'd iterate through the table whilst comparing each season `<td>` with the next, and adding a class if there is a difference.

However, I don't know how to do this using angularjs. Any help is appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

I decided to identify the last episode of each season by looping through the dataset on the server side, setting an approprioate boolean value for this, and then using `ng-class` on the UI. It seems simplier and neater than looping through the rendered HTML table.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Think of it differently...iterate through the data before passing to view and set a property something like `isLast` and use `ng-class` in view

Comment: share your response data it would help to understand more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$last` of `ng-repeat` and `ng-class` to style the last episode of each season

Data

```
$scope.shows = [{
        "season" : "season 1",
        "episodes" :["episode 1","episode 2","episode 3"]
    },
    {
      "season" : "season 2",
      "episodes" : ["episode 1","episode 2","episode 3"]
    },
    {
      "season" : "season 3",
      "episodes" : ["episode 1","episode 2","episode 3"]
    }
    ];
```

```
<tbody ng-repeat="show in shows">
     <tr ng-class="$last ? 'endSeason' : ''" ng-repeat="episode in show.episodes">
      <td>{{show.season}}</td>
      <td>{{episode}}</td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/7p4k41Lf/1/)**

Comment: This is definitely the simplest solution if you're ok with preprocessing the data into seasons! Although, might I suggest the simpler syntax would just be `ng-class="'end-season': $last'"`? I also slug-cased the class name, because that's more typical in class names :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bind to controller syntax.

```
<div ng-repeat="episode in $ctrl.episodes" ng-class="'final-of-type': $ctrl.isDifferent($index);'"></div>
```

Then in your directive:

```
this.episodes = data; // not sure how you're getting this
this.isDifferent = function(i) {
     return (i === episodes.length - 1) || (episodes[i].season !== episodes[i + 1].season)
}
```

That should do it or you.

Comment: You should sort episodes by season. And what will be if first season consists of the only one episode?

Comment: Sorry, based on the data he presented, I assumed it was already sorted. And it should work even if the first season consists of only one episode, because the list contains all episodes for all seasons, not just one particular season.

Comment: first item will never have particular class, because it will have `$index == 0` and you have `index > 0` condition. And from whence you know that each season has more than one episode?

Comment: Oh, the code is wrong anyways, I was adding a class to the first one with a NEW season. Fixed.

Comment: THERE. ARE YOU HAPPY NOW?! Haha, jk, think I fixed it though, assuming the expression evaluation bails out after the first truthy value in a series of OR evaluations, which I think it does, if I remember right. Thanks for the critique :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) to group all series by seasons and then iterate through out each individual season and mark `$last` series with desired class(*final-of-type*):

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.episodes = [
    {season:'1',episode:'2'},
    {season:'2',episode:'1'},
    {season:'1',episode:'1'},
    {season:'1',episode:'3'},
    {season:'2',episode:'2'},
    {season:'0',episode:'1'}
    ]
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

```css
.final-of-type {
background-color:grey;
}
td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-filter@*" data-semver="0.5.7" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Season</th>
            <th>Episode</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in ::episodes | groupBy: 'season' | orderBy: 'key'">
          <tr ng-repeat="episode in ::value | orderBy: 'episode'" ng-class="{'final-of-type': $last}">
            <td>{{::episode.season}}</td>
            <td>{{::episode.episode}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Down voted due to filters in dom. They can have pretty heavy performance implications due to being run every digest cycle. If sorting needs to be done, it should be done in the controller when the data is retrieved.

Comment: For you I added one-time binding `::`

Comment: Downvote removed. Still think preprocessing it would be better, but at least it won't run a bajillion times now.